# ApplicationId versus PackageName issue with new flavor

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

I have developed a new flavor of my application. Now when uploading it on the store, I have an error : "You need to use a different package name..." because the first version of the app is already on the store.

I have followed this recommendation.
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

I need a new manifest file for this new flavor, so I deleted the `<manifest>` attribute `package="..."` in the manifest of my new flavor.

As stated at the bottom of the above mentioned page:
NOTE 2:
*The package name must always be specified in the default AndroidManifest.xml file. If you have multiple manifests (e.g. a flavor specific manifest or a buildType specific manifest), the package name is optional, but if it is specified it must be identical to the package specified d in the main manifest.*

So now I run into this problem:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:process***Manifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@name value=(.***Application) from AndroidManifest.xml:25:9-49
>       is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:25:9-49 value=(***.HomeOnTheSpotApplication).
>       Suggestion: add `'tools:replace="android:name"'` to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-147:19 to override.

So I tried to add `tools:replace="android:name"` to the application application element but then I had this error (app crashing when starting):

FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application newFlavor.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "***.*Application" on path: /data/app/***.apk

I also tried to add 'tools:node="replace"' to the application element
But then it throws this message when trying to start the application:
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp="flavor2".***/"flavor1".***.activity.splash.SplashActivity_ }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {"flavor2".***/"flavor1".***.activity.splash.SplashActivity_} does not exist.

I'm out of ideas now :/

Comment: Manifest can have same package name. For google play, different application mustq have a different application Id. So, for multi flavors, you should change the applicationId in nuild.gradle. Manifest almost dont need any change

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my build.gradle already contains applicationId for the new flavor, with a different package name

Comment: Please, share both build.gradle and manifest file to help you. I have two apps in GooglePaly and I have only one Manifest File. I have custom views and I can access them via package name without any issue. Then, in build.gradle, I define two build flavor with different applicationId for both.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share this as the company name must be hidden... I need in my case two manifests files... But I have the same thing as you (applicationId defined for the new flavor). I just ran into a new problem when uploading the app on the store because "package= ... of manifest tag was the same in the new flavor manifest. So, because it is optional,  I removed it a ran into new problems...

Comment: Ok. No problem. build.gradle has two ApplicationID? And manifest file has two different packageName?

Comment: I just resolved the problem by deleting the android:name=".***" of my second (new flavor) manifest file. To respond you, yes build.gradle has an applicationId specified for the new flavor. and I just deleted the package name attribute (and the application name as well)  in the new manifest file. it works now...